# ROS cannot be compiled, tested on RPI 3 and 4

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed the latest version of raspbian on both RPI 3 and 4 and it just does not compile

```
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/rospack/include/rospack/rospack.h:108:10: fatal error: boost/tr1/unordered_set.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I first read it was becos RPI4 was too new, but apparently something is broken

I followed this tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

I use : 2019-09-26-raspbian-buster.img

how can I fix this ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342556/ros-cannot-be-compiled,-tested-on-rpi-3-and-4/) by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is currently no version of ROS targeting Debian Buster.
It looks like you're trying to install a version of ROS [targeting an older version of boost (<1.63)](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) than the one available on your system (Buster 1.67). In your version these headers don't exist anymore.

The header names have been updated in later versions of ROS https://github.com/ros/rospack/pull/80.

You could to try to compile ROS Melodic rather than ROS Kinetic that [targets more recent OSes](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#melodic-morenia-may-2018-may-2023).
You should be able to follow the same instructions and just replace `kinetic` with `melodic` in the commands.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-01-25**:
jolly good, I'll give it a try, I am a complete noob, so...
thanks

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-01-26**:
ok so it works, it crashed on compilation but I just reran it with the -j2 option

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-01-26**:
Glad it worked for you,

You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark, this will let the community know that this has been solved and doesn't need additional invstigation